# After Effects: Apply motion tracking to a scaled layer

Tags: after-effects, tracking

After effects 10.5 (CS 5.5)

I have two clips

- a layer with a smoke wisp curling up, much bigger than it will appear
- a layer with some slightly shaky footage of a broken machine just sitting there

I want to make the smoke wisp curl up from the machine, scaled to the footage.

The current set up:

- the footage with the machine is the main footage
- I've made a Tracker in that layer tracking the machine… the positions look right
- the Tracker targets the smoke

The problem is:

- if the smoke clip is scaled properly, the tracking motion on the smoke is not visible
- I discovered this is because the tracking is applied before the scale - so the differences in position become tiny

I speculate a solution might involve having the Tracking information applied to the smoke layer AFTER it's been scaled.

QUESTION(s):

1. how do I get the Tracking information applied to the smoke layer
   AFTER it's been scaled?
2. …or am I doing this wrong?  If so, how would I achieve this effect?

Comment: update: The solution may have something to do with making a new Null Object, applying the tracking information to that object, and then parenting the smoke to that layer

Comment: Looks similar to the answer for http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12758/zooming-in-on-one-layer-in-after-effects?rq=1